# HTML elements are overlapping

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a Login page. The problem is when i try to minimize the page the save copy check box and the send button are overlapped. i'm assuming i need to change something in the CSS. But i'm not sure exactly what. Here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/talamusiclover/ctqgkxcw/

```html
  <!DOCTYPE>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\etashah\Desktop\email.css">
    
    <div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <form name="myForm" ng-controller="emailController">
              <div class="form-group1" >
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Contacts</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email.text" >
              </div>
              <div role="alert">
                  <span class="error alert" ng-show="myForm.$error.required">
                    Required!</span>
                  <span class="error alert" ng-show="myForm.$error.email">
                    Not valid email!</span>
              </div>
    
          <div class="form-group2">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group3">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="blueBox">
              <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-10">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label class="checkboxLable"><input type="checkbox">Save a copy</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class= "button">
                <div class="col-sm-u-8 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
        <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"> </script>
        <script src= "C:\Users\etashah\Desktop\email\controller.js"> </script>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pull-right` class to keep the checkbox in right side. Then it will.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **position: relative;** from your button css, then your css for the button is:

```
.button {
color: #4CAF50;
font-size: 25px;
border-radius: 30px;
color: black;
right: 10px;
bottom: 30px;
}
```

The problem is, that your HTML code used bootstrap grid system while you overwriting them in your css file.You can read more about Bootstrap here [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)